# How to decide on what unit tests to create for a rules-based system

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I've been reading a lot about Unit Testing and am strongly considering using it with C++ and TDD for the first time. The problem I have is that of all the examples that I see in creating tests, they appear too trivial when I think about how to begin writing tests for the project I'm about to develop. It may be that I'm missing the point of Unit tests, so please let me know if this is the case here.

It's easy to understand a function that, for example checks prime numbers. It has a simple input (the number to test) and a simple output (true or false). It is easy to understand and create a unit test here.

Now, let's take, for example, a firewall application that has a configuration file of rules and an evaluation engine to evaluate those rules in a particular order, for specific inputs; the details of a network packet such as IP, subnet, port, domain etc.

Without writing unit tests, I would think to start by writing a parser to parse the rules config file into classes and then write a rules engine to compare given network packets with the rules in those classes, stepping through the rules in the order they were parsed until a match was found.

Unit tests and TDD states that before writing code, tests that fail should be written first. Therefore, in the case of the firewall project, would you start by writing tests that check the parsing of the file by creating a mock file to provide a specific set of rules, or is this just testing reading of a file, which is not usually recommended for unit tests, but rather integration tests? If tests are to be done here, what should be tested?

Also, how would one think about writing tests for such a rules engine to evaluate the rules? If details of a network packet are the input, the output would be whether or not the packet is accepted, rejected or ignored. Such a test is almost identical to what the rules engine is doing, so how could this be broken down into small "unit" tests?

Answer (score 1):

You need tests for your parser. For a given input string, make sure the correct rule object comes out. This does not access files, because your parser should not be tightly coupled to file I/O.

You need tests for every rule. Make sure the rule gives the results you want it to for given packets. This is probably the most important part; be sure to test edge cases thoroughly. You *don't* want any of these rules to misbehave, because they will be bombarded by malicious input.

And you need tests for the rule system. Write simple test rules and use them to make sure that the rule system correctly dispatches packets and acts on the responses.

All of these can easily be written before the actual code.

Comment: If the config file is XML, then do you mean I should supply XML fragments to the parser as input, with a class object as output for testing? Also, "need tests for every rule", if a single rule has 10 properties, and nearly an endless combination of rules, how can I create a test for every one of them? It may be just a port number that changes, or an IP may be a range of IPs, or a wild card. Any combination of properties may be used. That's thousands of possibilities.

Comment: The art of unit testing is to find a representative set of inputs. Code coverage tools help.